# Zoopla API - Output Data (XML)

Tags: php, xml

I'm attempting to use the Zoopla API (http://developer.zoopla.com/docs/read/Property_listings) to output specific data.

I have tested the API using a simple echo after the "file_get_contents() method, which shows the data. Example code shown below (API Key Removed)

```
$url = "http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml?postcode=CF11&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$zoopla = file_get_contents($url);
echo $zoopla;
```

What Im trying to code is a loop that will allow me to add html tags so that I can style them. I've done similar for a RSS feed but can't figure out a way for this XML.

I have also tried an alternative approach using simplexml_load_file()

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$agent_address = $xml->agent_address->agent_address[1]->agent_address;
echo $agent_address;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question!

Basically the $URL is a string and not a file "simplexml_load_file()"

So first, we need to get the xml file as a string and then parse the file. Code as followed! Works like a treat!

```
$zoopla = file_get_contents('http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml?postcode=CF64&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$properties = simplexml_load_string($zoopla);
echo $properties->listing[2]->agent_phone;
```

Comment: You know theirs a JSON version, right? Much easier to work with!